# backbone.js and jquery mobile: click on a fragment link (#something) causes a scroll to top of page

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I'm using jquery mobile and backbone.js to create a single page mobile application. The idea is that all data is local to the client and external data is captured via ajax. This app is intended to be deployed using Phonegap.

I'm using jqm just for the general look & feel, style, animations, page changes etc.
Backbone.js is used for handling the application model, server syncs, template rendering and routing. 
To prevent conflict between both libraries, all ajax-related functions in jqm have been disabled:

```
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
$.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
$.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
```

The main page loads a menu where each element takes you to a different application view. When you click on an element, data is retrieved using AJAX, HTML is generated on the fly and appended to the DOM, and the application changes to that page. Routing is done with url fragments for a wider browser support:

```
<a href="#news">News</a>
```

The code above makes the backbone route to perform the needed operations to retrieve the latests news form the server and render a page.
All of this works flawlessly.

My problem: when I click on an element of the menu, the FIRST thing it does (before even execute any of my code) is perform a scroll to the top of the screen. 
It does not seem a terrible problem but that unintended scrolling messes up the loading indicator that jqm shows when making an ajax call. 
If the device this application is running in does not support the `fixed` css property, the loading indicator is positioned near the clicked element. So, if the viewport scrolls to the top, the loading indicator remains at the original position. as result, the loading indicador gets partially or totally hidden.

Any idea why this could be happening? I've tried using Visual Event to search for strange click events attached by jquery / jquery mobile with no success, so I must be missing something.

Thanks in advance!

Edit to add more information about libraries I'm using

jquery: v1.6.2

jqm: v1.1.0 (also v1.0 for blackberry devices, but the behaviour does not change between jqm versions)

backbone.js: 0.9.2 (latest as this time of writing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the default behavior of any link with something like this:

```
<a href="#news" onclick="return false;">News</a>
```

You can use [more sophisticated technics](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault).

Comment: Ok, calling directly to the backbone router methods to redirect to an specific page AND adding the `return false` code directly on the onclick handler of the anchor just made the trick. So basically I'm performing the routing manually instead of letting backbone watch the URL hash changes. 

I would like to know why the view scrolls to the top, but that's just for the pleasure of knowing. You answered my question and saved my day, and that's the most important thing. Thank you!

Comment: The whole behavior of the click is just the same than before you added the `return false;` the only thing is being removed is the last part of the _event chain_, the native _link event_, the one that is looking for an DOM element with id like `news` and moving the scroll there or to the top of the page if none found. Just the behavior you don't want.

Comment: Ok, so the main problem is that i didn't correctly understood how native link events behave. :)

Thank you very much for the additional info @fguillen